# Get all dates between a start and end date into an array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I cant insert the result into an array.

This is my code:

```
$listData2="";

$end = date("n/d/Y",strtotime($row['dDate']));
$start = date("n/d/Y",strtotime($row['aDate']));

$datediff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$datediff = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));

for($i = 0; $i <=- $datediff + 1; $i++) {
    $dateArr=date("n/d/Y", strtotime($start . ' + ' . $i . 'day'));
    $listData2[]=$dateArr;
}
```

Comment: Also please consider to read this for your next question (or to improve your current question): http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You have a convoluted way to doing this so I am going to just show you how to get all of the dates between two dates into an array:

```
$listData2 = [];
$start     = new DateTime($row['dDate']);
$end       = (new DateTime($row['aDate']))->modify('+1 day');
$interval  = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period    = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $listData2[] =  $dt->format("n/d/Y");
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/306715)

This initializes an empty array to store the dates (you started with an empty string, not an array) and the creates the starting date and end date as [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects (instead of non-standard strings that you created. It then creates a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object representing 1 day and a [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) object to wrap ity all up for us to work with. Then we loop through the DatePeriod object and add them to the array.

(You also had an invalid operator (`<=-`) in your for loop).

Comment: is there no way that my code be in array? i cant understand that coding u used...

Comment: This code does put it into an array. Did you read the whole answer?

Comment: I added a demo so you can see it working. Hopefully that helps it make sense to you.

Comment: @JohnConde You got a fancy demo button there :D (BTW: `<=-` is technical not an invalid operator it just threads the variable as negative number e.g. `$x = 5;
 for($i = -10; $i <=- $x+1; $i++)
  echo $i . "<br>";` But I don't think this is what OP intended to do)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code:

```
$listData2 = array();
$end = date("n/d/Y",strtotime($row['dDate']));
$start = date("n/d/Y",strtotime($row['aDate']));
for(;;) {
    $listData2[]=date("n/d/Y", strtotime($start));
    $start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start)));
    if(strtotime($start)>strtotime($end)) break;
}
```

Comment: Your abuse of strtotime() is kinda scary